# How can I add multiple inline policy on AWS permission set using terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I've created 2 policies and tried to attach as an inline policy on AWS SSO permission sets. However, it only applies either one of policy. How can I apply both policies as inline policy on SSO permission set?

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "DenyAccess_nonUSRegions" {
name        = "DenyAccess_nonUSRegions"
description = "DenyAccess_nonUSRegions"
policy      = data.aws_iam_policy_document.DenyAccess_nonUSRegions.json
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "role" {
name        = "Deny_Specific_IAM_Actions"
description = "Deny_Specific_IAM_Actions"
policy      = data.aws_iam_policy_document.Deny_Specific_IAM_Actions.json
}

resource "aws_ssoadmin_permission_set_inline_policy" "role" {
inline_policy      = data.aws_iam_policy_document.Deny_Specific_IAM_Actions.json
instance_arn       = aws_ssoadmin_permission_set.permission.instance_arn
permission_set_arn = aws_ssoadmin_permission_set.permission.arn
}

resource "aws_ssoadmin_permission_set_inline_policy" "DenyAccess_nonUSRegions" {
inline_policy      = data.aws_iam_policy_document.DenyAccess_nonUSRegions.json
instance_arn       = aws_ssoadmin_permission_set.permission.instance_arn
permission_set_arn = aws_ssoadmin_permission_set.permission.arn
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have only [one inline policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/singlesignon/latest/userguide/permissionsetcustom.html#permissionsetsinlineconcept). So in your case the policies overwrite each other, and you end up with only one. So you either create a single inline policy combining the two that you have, or create two managed policies (not inline).

Comment: I saw a comment where I can utilize for_each argument to attach multiple in-line policy for SSO permission sets. Is it incorrect information?

Comment: @sean1989 You can have only one. But you can have multiple managed policies.